# Client Error 500 in socialite google login laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I have a laravel project that has been integrated with Facebook login, but if I use Google login, the page raises a client error that is 500 server errors

**You can check on this website** 
https://indhri.asynchsolution.com
and login using google, 
don't worry, I will delete the database immediately if this problem is resolved

this is my SocialController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use App\SocialAccount;
use App\User;

class SocialiteController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        //$user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
         try {
            $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect('/auth/login');
        }
        //dd($user);
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);

        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect('/personal');
    }

    public function findOrCreateUser($socialUser, $provider)
    {
        $socialAccount = SocialAccount::where('provider_id', $socialUser->getId())
                        ->where('provider_name', $provider)
                        ->first();

        if($socialAccount) {
            return $socialAccount->user;
        } else {
            $user = User::where('email', $socialUser->getEmail())->first();

            if(! $user) {
                $user = User::create([
                    'username' => $socialUser->getName(),
                    'email' => $socialUser->getEmail()

                ]);
                $user->assignRole('Registered');
            }

            $user->socialAccounts()->create([
                'provider_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
                'provider_name' => $provider
            ]);

            return $user;
        }
    }
}
```

[This is the client error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXG4C.png)

[this is error on Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7C0z.png)

Comment: The error could be anything, click on the preview tab of inspection to find it

Comment: But for a startup, import `use Socialite;` and `use Auth;` and `use Exception;`

Comment: You must enable error logging to see errors in chrome dev tools, or read the error log in `storage/logs/laravel-2019-10-08.log`

Comment: local.ERROR:  {"exception":"[object] (Laravel\\Socialite\\Two\\InvalidStateException(code: 0):  at /home/asyj6686/public_html/sublaravel/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php:210) this is the error in log @Saly3301

Comment: Okay posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `SESSION_DOMAIN` in `.env` file

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=indhri.asynchsolution.com
```

or change `config/session.php` from `null` to `indhri.asynchsolution.com`

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

Clear the cache

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Reload auto-discovered packages

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And try it on a private window because old session cookies can cause an issue

Hope this helps

Comment: show error local.ERROR: Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` in logs

Comment: I posted an answer to solve the first issue, I won't write one answer to fix your entire application

Comment: this problem is solved for localhost but not for shared hosting, but I will check my console, maybe there is wrong setting or other